# how to POST html form securely between websites?

Tags: html, forms, post

We have several companies that want to add a referral form on their websites which will POST to my separate domain, to create a referral record.

However, I can see a robot parsing these forms and spamming our system with junk data or worse.

I can not give the customers an API Key because that would sit visible client side and potential to use. And the robot would pick it up anyway. So how is this possible to do?

CSRF protection was mentioned in other questions, but this only works within the same site. eg. a session variable.

Perhaps force them to do captcha? Do the captcha services all have a hash they post along that I can simply validate my side? I would have to support multiple captcha services depending which ones they all choose. So it might not be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by [asymmetric encryption](https://www.okta.com/identity-101/asymmetric-encryption/). SSL uses asymmetric encryption and you can even use [letsencrypt.org](https://letsencrypt.org/) for free.

This question seems to have been answered before and here is a [detailed answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/20833) on how SSL works.

A basic description is that if your browser (client) knows a public key, they can use it to determine if the communication is sent from a trusted source. The name itself (asymmetric encryption) means that it is a one-way method of encryption.  The public key cannot be used to determine the private key or to make sense of the data sent. This means that the bots will only see nonsense data and will never be able to know what it means.

Comment: SSL ensures the destination is legitimate (eg. my company). it does not ensure the source is legitimate. Not sure how you see this as a solution. I believe origins can be fudged and in fact they are only ip addresses, nothing to do with SSL.